# Webpak при сборке scss применяет не верный относительный путь к шрифту

Tags: webpack, scss, loader

Правила загрузчиков у меня такие:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: 'file-loader?name=./fonts/[name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    },
```

И вот такая структура ФС:

```
C:\...\project\SRC
...
|
+---fonts
|       ...
|
\---scss
    |   main.scss
    |
    +---base
    |       typography.scss
    |
```

Файл typography содержит правила `@font-face` с относительными путями, ведущими в директорию fonts. Файл main содержит `@import "base/typography"`.
Сборка завершается с ошибкой по каждому из шрифтов

> Error: Can't resolve '../../fonts/font.ttf' in 'C:...\project\src\scss'

То есть относительный путь берётся не от файла typography, а от main.
При этом сменив пути в typography на верные относительно main получаю нормальную сборку.
Чего я не доделал?